# Как установить и настроить jabber server на ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xmpp, ubuntu

Подскажите все шаги, нечто вроде плана как установить и настроить jabber server на ubuntu 12.04. Заранее благодарен! Можно после плана примерно накидать код.. спс заранее

Comment: А в чем проблема? мануалов дофигищи.

Comment: Проблема в том что мануалов куча, не знаешь который взять ,по одному делаешь не работает, и пути решения не прилагаются! Служба не запускается. В виде плана что ли?!

Comment: пиши что делаешь, глядишь сам заведёшь :) я так сканер завёл на Ubuntu. Похвастаюсь -http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3838/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D1%84%D1%83-scx-4100-%D0%B2-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо определиться с выбором джаббер-сервера.
Все три самые популярные программы для создания сервера, имеют свои особенности:

[См. Сложности администрования разных Jabber серверов](http://wiki.404.city/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80)
( Ejaberd На Erland. Prosody на Lua. Openfire на  Java )

Потом стандартно в консоли **apt-get install "название"**  и вуаля, сервер установлен!

В этом нет ничего сложно, но в дальнейшем  в зависимости от выбора сервера. Разные команды, создания пользователей.

У Openfire и Ejaberd есть админки, где дальнейшая инструкция сводиться к банальному: Нажми туда,  Нажми сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [так](http://www.aaaweb.ru/2011/07/07/ustanovka-jabber-servera-openfire-na-ubuntu-11-04/),быстро разворачивается, легко админится, на BSD разворачивал. Из недостатков (по крайней мере у меня), не предсказуемые падения были, но лечится легко.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите готовую сборку Spark (server + клиенты). хорошо ставится в компаниях - поддержка авторизации AD, LDAP